# TextInputLayout move the hint label and change it's background color when focused

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android, android-textinputedittext

I am trying to customize materials `TextInpuLayout.OutlinedBox` and `TextInputEditText`.

My current state is like following image

[image]

What I want to do is remove the background of the hint label so that it doesn't create that ugly cutout. Like this:

[image]

Or if that isn't possible moving the label above the input would also do the trick:

[image]

It would be nice if this was achievable using styles so that I could easily apply this to other text input elements as well.
I'm pretty new to android so please be considerate.

Here's the code for the styling:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">@dimen/textInputCornerRadius</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">@dimen/textInputCornerRadius</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">@dimen/textInputCornerRadius</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">@dimen/textInputCornerRadius</item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/primaryDarkColorBackground</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_box_stroke</item>
</style>
<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">30dp</item>
</style>
```

And here is how I define my input in the layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/username_layout"
        style="@style/MyTheme"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:hint="@string/email_or_username"
        app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.10">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            style="@style/EditTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code what you have implemented so far ?

Comment: @Swayangjit it's just the default outlinedbox with a transparent box stroke, a background color and a little padding.

Comment: Share your xml code.

Comment: added some xml code for clarification.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm building a TextInputLayout component where I don't know which background it's going to be placed on and the HintText background has the same issue as first example from above/OP (square around text). Haven't found a way to programmatically target it either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can obtain it with the `TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox` style.
It is not exactly what you are looking for:

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Rounded"
        ..>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="30dp"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

With:

```
  <style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Rounded" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/Rounded_ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/input_text_no_underline</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Rounded_ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

The selector is used to remove the underline:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="0" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

[image]
[image]

**Note:** it requires the version 1.1.0 of the library.

Comment: Hi Gabriele, this answer is very useful to me that I'm facing the same problem. 
I followed your solution but the underline remains. I have put the selector in the color.xml file like this:
<color name="input_text_no_underline">
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
.....
Maybe the problem is ?attr/colorOnSurface? I don't have the attr directory.
Thanks again for your help

Comment: @michelecasati Try to use the same color used in the background

Comment: I have understood the problem. I am using a gradient as a background, so the color won't match in both cases. I have to figure it out another solution, thanks anyway for your quick help

Answer (score -1):

Try setting on the `TextInputEditText`:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```